# Is there callback available for any RichResponse in Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a dialogflow requirement to present user a payment link, on the click of which I must hang on 20 seconds (show some busy image or something) and then call on the next Intent.

So far I have been able to present a link using LinkOutSuggestion/BasicCard button. But I do not have idea that how I can make my program proceed further. I know there is a approach to have user input something like "Check Payment", but can we skip this altogether and just pass on to next intent post click of that LinkOutSuggestion or BasicCard Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you could skip the part of the user having to input something in the chat is by using a [Suggestion](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/rich-responses#suggestion_chips). These suggestions cannot be added to a card or open a link, but they do continue the conversation with the text that is used, so you could add a suggestion saying Check Payment.

The linkout suggestion or buttons on card do not support a click event or the possibility to continue the conversation.